# Как обработать исключение MySql?

Tags: исключения, php, sql, mysql

Как можно обработать исключительную ситуацию, возникшую при работе с `MySQL` СУБД в `PHP`? Например, если при попытке соединения что-то пошло не так, и соединение не удалось, то как это обработать? Есть ли такой класс исключений? В `PDO`, например, есть свой класс для работы с исключениями. А есть ли что-то подобное для обработки исключений в штатных классах?

**Спасибо!**

---

Нашел вот такой штатный класс:

```
MySQLi_Sql_Exception
```

Но это вовсе не то....

Comment: и чем же Вам PDO не угодил?

Comment: Просто уже много кода написано с использованием штатных средств PHP для работы с базами данных. А так, полностью согласен с вами, @FLK, PDO и правда лучший выбор был бы, и удобно, и безопасно....

Comment: Если используете нативный mysql_*, то лучше от него уйти. Ну если все уж совсем плохо, лень и.т.п - сделать обертку, накатать какие нужно exceptions. (ну или если используется mysqli, так же сделать для него обертку).

Answer (score 1):

Каждая `mysql` функция возвращает либо результат, либо код ошибки.

В данном случае, надо было заранее думать об обработке ошибок. Сейчас, как вариант, либо это всё дописывать, либо обернуть в `try{} catch{}`, либо зарегистрировать обработчик исключений на уровне `php`.